# I have CORS error with symfony 6 and angular

Tags: angular, symfony, cors

I have a CORS ERROR.
I use nelmio_cors bundle

the ERROR :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:8000/folder/new' from
> origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Request header field access-control-allow-methods is not allowed by
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

nelmio_cors.yaml :

```yaml
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin_regex: true
        allow_origin: ['http://localhost:4200/']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/': ~
```

bundles.php :
`Nelmio\CorsBundle\NelmioCorsBundle::class => ['all' => true],`

angular request :

```js
onSubmitFolder() {
  const folderForm = this.folderForm.value;
  this.http.post('https://localhost:8000/folder/new', folderForm).subscribe(
    (response) => {
      console.log(response);
      // Traitez la réponse de l'API Symfony ici
    },
    (error) => {
      console.error(error);
      // Traitez l'erreur ici
    }
  );
}
```

I hope someone can help, I have 0 solution...

Comment: Please read the error before asking Stackoverflow. And please search before asking questions. There are thousands of questions with this exact error message.

Comment: but you think i haven't tried it? Your message is of no use to me.

Comment: Some things to check: try to access your endpoint with postman and check if your endpoint fails. Sometimes it throws a CORS error when your code fails - al least, that is what I experienced. Other options. have you tried `allow_origin: ^https?://(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1)(:[0-9]+)?$ `?

Comment: ty, I will try as soon as possible